# Moderators editing answers without any explanation

Tags: discussion

I had a moderator edit my answers and am not clear on why.

As part of my answer I recommended using a generic third-party solution (without specifying the name of the third party). I followed that up with a specific third-party company solution that our company used that solved the same problem the user was having.

Third party solutions are recommended often on Stack Overflow.  Is there a policy against recommending a third party solution?

If this helps, the problem was with Oracle's free product, ODAC.  We moved off of ODAC and bought Devart's dotConnect connector and it solved all of our problems we had with ODAC.  Was this inappropriate to suggest?

Also, he took away points for each time I did this...

Comment: The post was probably flagged as spam; see the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), section 'self promotion'; adding a disclaimer with the recommendation might make it more palatable to the community.

Comment: Ah, you included that recommendation in **four of your answers**. The alternative was to delete all 4 posts instead.

Comment: Did you review [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers)?

Comment: [The question link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24532506/1043380), for those interested. Oh wait, that is just the most recent one. View the profile for the full list.

Comment: You included a recommendation for a product in 6 answers in the space of 20 minutes. That was in addition to three earlier recommendations. Put them all together and it starts to look like spam.  Also, you only lost points for two of those posts that had been upvoted, not all of them.

Comment: It was actually more than 10 answers by my count (some of them have since been deleted).

Comment: "he took away points" - moderators can't do that; only indirectly through deletion of an upvoted post of yours. And "Is there a policy against recommending a third party solution" - we have an off-topic reason for that: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for SSo as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam". Link-only answers and answers just recommending off-site content are aganst the SO policies as well. That said, recommendations are ok as long as your post still qualifies as an answer without the recommendation.

Comment: I am fine with removing the reference to the name of DevArt and their product if that is the case.  But what was removed was saying that other connectors do not have this problem and that ODAC is not the only option.  I don't work for Devart and have no reason to profit from it personally.  Our company did save a lot of time and money switching away from ODAC though and I thought I would pass that along.

Comment: @gunr2171  The part that was removed was the valuable part for this guys issue, ODAC makes you install the client on the server where devart and other clients do not make you install the client on the server.  That is a huge issue.

Comment: @Carl Veazey - Thanks for that reference, i am glad we have a policy like that here.  In my case, I am just a little happy that my experience and 12 months of work on this problem could be a value to future people.

Comment: @Andrew Medico - Yes, i have made it a point to educate those of us who came from a MS SQL back ground and were used to the MS connectors to be great.  I assumed that the free ODAC connector must also be good.  I was very wrong and paid for it.  It wasn't until a year ago when i met another former SQL guy who moved to Oracle who told me about this.  If it wasn't for that chance encounter I might not have known there were alternatives.

Comment: @Everyone  I will humbly take the feedback and learn from it.  thanks for indulging me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Judging by the fact that the edits in question appear to be removing extra mentions about  `devArt's dotConnect for oracle`, maybe he's removing them, because you don't need to mention `devArt's dotConnect for oracle` in your answer if you're not actually using it to answer the question.

Comment: IF he felt that the name of the product needed removing, that is fine. He should just have removed the name of the product and not the benefits of a third party solution. The point of it all was that the free connector is severely limited compared to the third party solutions and that using a third party solution would solve thier issue.

Comment: @PatrickWensel  What the comment was about isn't that important.   It's that your comment about the produce is not important at all to your answer.  If instead of writing `"check out this product"`, you wrote `"I like cake"`  The moderator would delete that too

Comment: @Everyone  I will humbly take the feedback and learn from it.  thanks for indulging me